# Click on checkbox using selenium python

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click on the checkbox for filtering documents on this page (https://products.mhra.gov.uk/search/?query=zoton&page=1) I want to select the checkbox for 
Summary of Product Characteristics (SPC) and I m using the code below which does not work. Please help me understand how to make it work.

```
#navigating to search page
 try :
        elem4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']")
        elem4.click()
        time.sleep(15)

        elem5 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
        elem5.click()
        time.sleep(15)

    except:
          pass

    try:
        elem = driver.find_element_by_id('filter-spc')
        elem.click()
    except:
          pass
```

[image]

Comment: Are you waiting until the checkbox appears?

Comment: Please post all of your relevant code as a [mcve].

Comment: @Sri I m waiting for 15 secs

Comment: @ggorlen edited and added more lines

Comment: `except: pass` is generally a bad idea. If there's a problem, you probably want to at least know it happened with a log, if not letting the error bring down the program. If this part is failing, then the rest of the clicks won't work, either so you might as well let the program crash and see what's really going on here. A full/complete example would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. You probably want to modify the css selector for the submit button, but the logic is there. This works for me.

```
url = "https://products.mhra.gov.uk/search/?query=zoton&page=1"

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "agree-checkbox"))
    )
    elem = browser.find_element_by_id('agree-checkbox')
    elem.click()
    submit = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#__next > div > main > div > div > section > div > form > button")
    submit.click()
except:
    print("Not found Agree")

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "filter-spc"))
    )
    elem = browser.find_element_by_id('filter-spc')
    elem.click()
except:
    print("Not found SPC")
```